# click on element is not working for each scenario in protractor

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, cucumber

I am so confused about the behavior of Protractor. I am writing my test cases with protractor and cucumber.
My scenario is: I need to click on drop down arrow and select an option. I am able to click the drop down and select an option for one scenario but the same click is failing on drop down for subsequent scenario.

```
var viewArrow=  await element(by.xpath("(//*[@class='mat-select-arrow-wrapper'])[2]"));
 browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(viewArrow),5000);
 await viewArrow.click().then ( async() =>{//selecting dropdown
var reqElement2 = await element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option .mat-option-text', dropDownChoice));
    await  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", reqElement2) ;   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
optionselect(option) { 
 return element(by.cssContainingText('option',option.toString())).click(); 
}
```

Create a function similar to this and pass the drop down value which needs to be selected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My problem is click on drop down is not working every time.